# Maximizing a Variable in Inequality

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, optimization, products

I have the following product:
$$\prod_{i=1}^m\left(2+\frac{1}{n+a_i}\right)\le\left(2+\frac{1}{n'}\right)^m$$
for some $n,m\in\mathbb{N}$. Here $a_i$ is a sequence where we know that following $a_{i+1}\ge a_i+1$, $a_1=0$. (Hence we have
$$\prod_{i=1}^m\left(2+\frac{1}{n+a_i}\right)\le\prod_{i=0}^{m-1}\left(2+\frac{1}{n+i}\right)$$
). I am trying to find the largest possible $n'$ (I don't need to actually find $\max(n')$, I am just in a situation where the larger I can get $n'$ the better).
It is clear that I can have $n'=n$, but I need a larger value. I was contemplating trying to find a $k$ such that $n'=n+km$ but I couldn't get anywhere. Can anyone help me find a valid $n'>n$?

Comment: I guess you want to know when m and n goes to infinity, what k you can have? You also want to some some relationship between m and n, for example m=n? Otherwise there are too many cases.

Comment: I think useful information can still be extracted without that knowledge. Clearly the denominator in the fraction is increasing, so the factors are clearly decreasing in value as the indexing increases. One could then get an upper bound by simply raising the first factor to the $m$-th power, but I am wondering if I could raise say the middle factor, or the average values of the factors, etc... to the $m$ power creating a smaller upper bound.